# Contribution form issue: cannot submit donation

Tags: civicontribute, contributions

It's Giving Tuesday and this donation form on my client's website won't allow credit card donors to submit their donations :o

https://apprenticelearning.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=3

When I've filled out all the information and try to submit a donation, this shows up (once Inspected):

VM625:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at v (eval at  (jquery.min.js?r=Z0KlZ:2), :1:694)
    at w (eval at  (jquery.min.js?r=Z0KlZ:2), :1:1555)
    at Object.eval (eval at  (jquery.min.js?r=Z0KlZ:2), :1:1450)
    at Object. (jquery.min.js?r=Z0KlZ:2)
    at i (jquery.min.js?r=Z0KlZ:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?r=Z0KlZ:2)
    at x (jquery.min.js?r=Z0KlZ:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js?r=Z0KlZ:4)

Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: You may help folk help you if you give more information such as what Payment Processor you are using, when it was last known to work, what has changed since then etc

Comment: looks like Stripe with WordPress but not using a shortcode - is that correct?

Comment: the client uses Stripe! not sure about shortcodes ...

Comment: Can you check your civi logs for any other error logs.

Comment: we found an issue with Stripe and the https://civicrm.org/extensions/percentage-price-field/ extension but i don't recall seeing that on your page. But, i wondered if you wanted to make the simplest possible Contribution form (ie not 'on behalf of org' or anything)  just in case there is something else there that is intefering, esp anything that uses js

Comment: thanks ... i tried removing various extra functions (like the "on behalf of an org" section) but no difference. i'm not sure how to check the civi log for error logs without resetting/making huge changes to the site ... thank you all for your feedback so far!

Comment: Yann, did you try the 'test drive' option (as opposed to live contribution) just to verify that it is the payment processor that is a problem? If you try 'test' drive you can still generation transactions but eliminate payment processor.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe uses javascript to submit the credit card credentials to the stripe server (so that they're never handled by the CiviCRM server). The console is showing that it's unable to do that because of javascript errors.

A browser may or may not stop processing if it encounters javascript errors, it depends on the browser/settings.

On your referenced page, it's CiviCRM loading the jquery.min.js file, so that suggests it's a purely CiviCRM issue - there's likely some Civi or extension javascript running that's trying to execute some jquery and getting an error.

As per Pete's comment, I'd start with thinking about what has changed since it was last working (e.g. a CiviCRM or extension update, a change with WordPress, etc.).